# Magento 1.7 CSV update product categories

Tags: magento, csv

I have a lot of products which need to be assigned to new categories. The products exist, the categories exist, but for some reason the import is not doing something.

I am using a dataflow profile using the following settings:

[image]
<sub>(source: [i.imm.io](http://i.imm.io/zsE2.png))</sub>

The first two lines of my CSV are:

```
sku,store,category_ids
TT010,default,Face/Acne
```

What values should the first line have in order to assign the products to another category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had to override the core/mage/catalog/model/convert/adapter/product.php file.

I added the following code after

```
if (isset($importData['category_ids'])) {
    $product->setCategoryIds($importData['category_ids']);
}
```

---

```
//search for a category by name.
if(isset($importData['category']))
{
  $cat_ids = array();
  $cats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
      ->getCollection()
      ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
      ->load();
  foreach($cats as $cat)
  {
    if($cat->getName() == end(explode('/',$importData['category'])))
    {
      $cat_ids[] = $cat->getId();
    }
  }
  $product->setCategoryIds($cat_ids);
}
```

This is for magento 1.7

Comment: hi can you please have a look at http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6074/import-products-with-multiple-categories